# how to use .DataBodyRange.Delete for each Listobject table in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, listobject

I am attempting to loop through multiple tables within a single workbook and clear the data on those tables so that new data can be entered. As the row counts, column counts, names, and number of tables can change I was hoping to create a single macro to loop through the tables and perform .DataBodyRange.Delete

**Working Code for 1 table called by sheet and object name:**

I also found this code on a forum and I believe the IF portion takes into account a table that is already empty so that no error is thrown.

```
Sub ResetTable()
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").ListObjects("ListObjectName")
        If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
            .DataBodyRange.Delete
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**My attempt at turning this into a more dynamic loop:**

The second set of code is failing on With ws **.tbl** due to a *Compile error: Method or data member not found.* So I am looking for any help in either fixing the below code or using an entirely different path.

```
Sub ResetAllTables()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim ws As Worksheet

'Loop through each sheet and table in the workbook
  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
      'Do something to all the tables...
        With ws.tbl
            If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
                .DataBodyRange.Delete
            End If
        End With
        tbl.ShowTotals = True     
    Next tbl
  Next sht
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: But guessing that you just neeed `With tbl`.

Comment: Updated to clarify, and yes the code is failing on .tbl with a compile error: method or data member not found. This makes me think something isn't defined properly but I'm not sure the correct way to fix it. thanks!

Comment: Did you try changing `With ws.tbl` to just `With tbl`?

Comment: ......I cant believe thats all it was...... [insert head banging emoji]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as suggested by BigBen & SRJ,

changing `with ws.tbl` to just `with tbl` fixed the issue. also had to fix `Next sht` to be `Next ws`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well actually [@SJR suggested it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57980101/how-to-use-databodyrange-delete-for-each-listobject-table-in-a-workbook#comment102369670_57980101), but anyway glad to help.

Comment: `tbl` is not a member of `ws` (i.e. the `Excel.Worksheet` class), that's why `ws.tbl` isn't working. Also, `Next sht` or `Next ws` should be just `Next` ;-)